# Как правильно записать регулярное выражение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый вечер, подскажите пожалуйста, как мне выбрать то что обвел прямоугольниками?
Вроде простая задача, но я уже закипаю)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

единственный символ по которому можно отделить свойства это двоеточие. после названия свойства идет двоеточие, и в нем может быть несколько значений которые почему то отделены от следующего свойства такой же запятой. мне надо как то заменить эти запятые отделяющие свойства на уникальный символ.

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Если у тебя все такого вида то во многих языках есть Split. В качестве разделителя запятая. Получишь массив.

Comment: @Slava `мне надо как то заменить эти запятые отделяющие свойства на уникальный символ` - а на какой символ нужно произвести замену?

Comment: спасибо всем огромное!
bukkojot и Grigory отдельное)
воспользовался решением bukkojot

Answer (score 0):

```
     split(/,\s+(?=[^,:]+:)/);
```

Это разделит строчку на части в Perl

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле название свойства перед запятой начинается с большой буквы и вплоть до двоеточия не содержит запятых, поэтому первая часть регэкспа достаточно понятна. А вот дальше нужен позитивный просмотр вперед, те чтобы дальше шел либо конец строки, либо пробел + текст с большой буквы без запятых вплоть до двоеточия.

```
[А-ЯA-Z]{1}[\w\s]*:.*?(?=(\s*[A-ZА-Я]{1}[\w\s]*:)|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Уточняющих комментариев от ТС не было, поэтому предположительно написал разделитель в виде точки *(что вполне логично, т.к. это конец данных)*. На PHP решение будет выглядеть так:

```
<?php

$str = 'Тип оборудования: Топливозаборник подогреваемый, Напряжение: 12В, 24В, Размер лифта: 0-50мм,';

$patt = '~(?<!,),(\s?)(?=[А-ЯЁ]|$)~';
$repl = '.$1';

echo preg_replace($patt, $repl, $str);
```

> Результат:

```
Тип оборудования: Топливозаборник подогреваемый. Напряжение: 12В, 24В. Размер лифта: 0-50мм.
```